# Cassandra Configurations and installation

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, pycassa, nosql

I have using cassandra on CentOS6. I have installed java, download and un-tared cassandra tar, started cassandra using:

```
bin/cassandra
```

then using cqlsh from coppied files:

```
bin/cqlsh
```

Now on cqlsh everything is working fine, I have created keyspace, created table and tested queries, but when I am trying to import csv file of approx 198GB then I got error after 5 minutes for rpc timeout, while there is no Timeout in conf/cassandra.yaml configuration file named rpc, I have increased write timeout to 20000ms but no improvement. Then I opted for solution of pycassa and tried to import using inserts commands but then after some times with insertions of 30K to 180K records program failed with timeout error.

```
pycassa.pool.AllServersUnavailable: An attempt was made to connect to each of the servers twice, but none of the attempts succeeded. The last failure was timeout: timed out
```

Should I need to install it properly. other thing what we noticed is that while copying Data it's very slow and not using server resources and while using Copy Command it should have used memory and processor to it's peak capacity as there is no other process is running. Can you suggest Configuration settings?

My Node is up and running?

```
nodetool status
Note: Ownership information does not include topology; for complete information, specify a keyspace
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Owns   Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  25.54 MB   100.0%  6bc340b2-4534-400f-b23d-9fe3ed0c6971  -9120530846114649324                     rack1
```

Server Configuration:

OS CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
hdd 8Tb all SSD Drives
RAM 32GB
Proccessor: model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz, 24 Core(2 physical processors with 12 cores each)

conf/cassandra.yaml

```
# Cassandra storage config YAML 

cluster_name: 'Test Cluster'

# multiple tokens per node, see http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations
num_tokens: 256

# that do not have vnodes enabled.
# initial_token:

hinted_handoff_enabled: true
max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours
hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024
max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024

authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

permissions_validity_in_ms: 2000

partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:
    - /data/cassandra/data

# commit log
commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

disk_failure_policy: stop

commit_failure_policy: stop

# Default value is empty to make it "auto" (min(5% of Heap (in MB), 100MB)). Set to 0 to disable key cache.
key_cache_size_in_mb:

# Default is 14400 or 4 hours.
key_cache_save_period: 14400

# Default value is 0, to disable row caching.
row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

# Duration in seconds after which Cassandra should
# safe the row cache. Caches are saved to saved_caches_directory as specified
# in this configuration file.
#
# Saved caches greatly improve cold-start speeds, and is relatively cheap in
# terms of I/O for the key cache. Row cache saving is much more expensive and
# has limited use.
#
# Default is 0 to disable saving the row cache.
row_cache_save_period: 0

# Number of keys from the row cache to save
# Disabled by default, meaning all keys are going to be saved
# row_cache_keys_to_save: 100

# The off-heap memory allocator.  Affects storage engine metadata as
# well as caches.  Experiments show that JEMAlloc saves some memory
# than the native GCC allocator (i.e., JEMalloc is more
# fragmentation-resistant).
#
# Supported values are: NativeAllocator, JEMallocAllocator
#
# If you intend to use JEMallocAllocator you have to install JEMalloc as library and
# modify cassandra-env.sh as directed in the file.
#
# Defaults to NativeAllocator
# memory_allocator: NativeAllocator

# saved caches
saved_caches_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches

# commitlog_sync: batch
# commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms: 50
#
# It should be at least as large as the concurrent_writes setting.
commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000
# commitlog_periodic_queue_size:

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"

# your system; (8 * number_of_cores) is a good rule of thumb.
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32

# Total memory to use for sstable-reading buffers.  Defaults to
# the smaller of 1/4 of heap or 512MB.
# file_cache_size_in_mb: 512

# Total memory to use for memtables.  Cassandra will flush the largest
# memtable when this much memory is used.
# If omitted, Cassandra will set it to 1/4 of the heap.
# memtable_total_space_in_mb: 2048

# Total space to use for commitlogs.  Since commitlog segments are
# mmapped, and hence use up address space, the default size is 32
# on 32-bit JVMs, and 1024 on 64-bit JVMs.
#
# If space gets above this value (it will round up to the next nearest
# segment multiple), Cassandra will flush every dirty CF in the oldest
# segment and remove it.  So a small total commitlog space will tend
# to cause more flush activity on less-active columnfamilies.
# commitlog_total_space_in_mb: 4096

# This sets the amount of memtable flush writer threads.  These will
# be blocked by disk io, and each one will hold a memtable in memory
# while blocked. If you have a large heap and many data directories,
# you can increase this value for better flush performance.
# By default this will be set to the amount of data directories defined.
#memtable_flush_writers: 1

# the number of full memtables to allow pending flush, that is,
# waiting for a writer thread.  At a minimum, this should be set to
# the maximum number of secondary indexes created on a single CF.
memtable_flush_queue_size: 4

# Whether to, when doing sequential writing, fsync() at intervals in
# order to force the operating system to flush the dirty
# buffers. Enable this to avoid sudden dirty buffer flushing from
# impacting read latencies. Almost always a good idea on SSDs; not
# necessarily on platters.
trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

# TCP port, for commands and data
storage_port: 7000

# SSL port, for encrypted communication.  Unused unless enabled in
# encryption_options
ssl_storage_port: 7001

# Address to bind to and tell other Cassandra nodes to connect to. You
# _must_ change this if you want multiple nodes to be able to
# communicate!
#
# Leaving it blank leaves it up to InetAddress.getLocalHost(). This
# will always do the Right Thing _if_ the node is properly configured
# (hostname, name resolution, etc), and the Right Thing is to use the
# address associated with the hostname (it might not be).
#
# Setting this to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.
listen_address: localhost

# Address to broadcast to other Cassandra nodes
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address
# broadcast_address: 1.2.3.4

# Internode authentication backend, implementing IInternodeAuthenticator;
# used to allow/disallow connections from peer nodes.
# internode_authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllInternodeAuthenticator

# Whether to start the native transport server.
# Please note that the address on which the native transport is bound is the
# same as the rpc_address. The port however is different and specified below.
start_native_transport: true
# port for the CQL native transport to listen for clients on
native_transport_port: 9042
# The maximum threads for handling requests when the native transport is used.
# This is similar to rpc_max_threads though the default differs slightly (and
# there is no native_transport_min_threads, idle threads will always be stopped
# after 30 seconds).
# native_transport_max_threads: 128
#
# The maximum size of allowed frame. Frame (requests) larger than this will
# be rejected as invalid. The default is 256MB.
# native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb: 256

# Whether to start the thrift rpc server.
start_rpc: true

# The address to bind the Thrift RPC service and native transport
# server -- clients connect here.
#
# Leaving this blank has the same effect it does for ListenAddress,
# (i.e. it will be based on the configured hostname of the node).
#
# Note that unlike ListenAddress above, it is allowed to specify 0.0.0.0
# here if you want to listen on all interfaces, but that will break clients
# that rely on node auto-discovery.
rpc_address: localhost
# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160

# enable or disable keepalive on rpc connections
rpc_keepalive: true

# Cassandra provides two out-of-the-box options for the RPC Server:
#
# sync  -> One thread per thrift connection. For a very large number of clients, memory
#          will be your limiting factor. On a 64 bit JVM, 180KB is the minimum stack size
#          per thread, and that will correspond to your use of virtual memory (but physical memory
#          may be limited depending on use of stack space).
#
# hsha  -> Stands for "half synchronous, half asynchronous." All thrift clients are handled
#          asynchronously using a small number of threads that does not vary with the amount
#          of thrift clients (and thus scales well to many clients). The rpc requests are still
#          synchronous (one thread per active request).
#
# The default is sync because on Windows hsha is about 30% slower.  On Linux,
# sync/hsha performance is about the same, with hsha of course using less memory.
#
# Alternatively,  can provide your own RPC server by providing the fully-qualified class name
# of an o.a.c.t.TServerFactory that can create an instance of it.
rpc_server_type: sync

# Uncomment rpc_min|max_thread to set request pool size limits.
#
# Regardless of your choice of RPC server (see above), the number of maximum requests in the
# RPC thread pool dictates how many concurrent requests are possible (but if you are using the sync
# RPC server, it also dictates the number of clients that can be connected at all).
#
# The default is unlimited and thus provides no protection against clients overwhelming the server. You are
# encouraged to set a maximum that makes sense for you in production, but do keep in mind that
# rpc_max_threads represents the maximum number of client requests this server may execute concurrently.
#
# rpc_min_threads: 16
# rpc_max_threads: 2048

# uncomment to set socket buffer sizes on rpc connections
# rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes:
# rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes:

# Uncomment to set socket buffer size for internode communication
# Note that when setting this, the buffer size is limited by net.core.wmem_max
# and when not setting it it is defined by net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
# See:
# /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
# /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
# and: man tcp
# internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes:
# internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes:
# Frame size for thrift (maximum message length).
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

# Set to true to have Cassandra create a hard link to each sstable
# flushed or streamed locally in a backups/ subdirectory of the
# keyspace data.  Removing these links is the operator's
# responsibility.
incremental_backups: false

# Whether or not to take a snapshot before each compaction.  Be
# careful using this option, since Cassandra won't clean up the
# snapshots for you.  Mostly useful if you're paranoid when there
# is a data format change.
snapshot_before_compaction: false

# Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
# or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true
# should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
# lose data on truncation or drop.
auto_snapshot: true

# When executing a scan, within or across a partition, we need to keep the
# tombstones seen in memory so we can return them to the coordinator, which
# will use them to make sure other replicas also know about the deleted rows.
# With workloads that generate a lot of tombstones, this can cause performance
# problems and even exaust the server heap.
# (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets)
# Adjust the thresholds here if you understand the dangers and want to
# scan more tombstones anyway.  These thresholds may also be adjusted at runtime
# using the StorageService mbean.
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000

# Add column indexes to a row after its contents reach this size.
# Increase if your column values are large, or if you have a very large
# number of columns.  The competing causes are, Cassandra has to
# deserialize this much of the row to read a single column, so you want
# it to be small - at least if you do many partial-row reads - but all
# the index data is read for each access, so you don't want to generate
# that wastefully either.
column_index_size_in_kb: 64

# Size limit for rows being compacted in memory.  Larger rows will spill
# over to disk and use a slower two-pass compaction process.  A message
# will be logged specifying the row key.
in_memory_compaction_limit_in_mb: 64

# Number of simultaneous compactions to allow, NOT including
# validation "compactions" for anti-entropy repair.  Simultaneous
# compactions can help preserve read performance in a mixed read/write
# workload, by mitigating the tendency of small sstables to accumulate
# during a single long running compactions. The default is usually
# fine and if you experience problems with compaction running too
# slowly or too fast, you should look at
# compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec first.
#
# concurrent_compactors defaults to the number of cores.
# Uncomment to make compaction mono-threaded, the pre-0.8 default.
#concurrent_compactors: 1

# Multi-threaded compaction. When enabled, each compaction will use
# up to one thread per core, plus one thread per sstable being merged.
# This is usually only useful for SSD-based hardware: otherwise,
# your concern is usually to get compaction to do LESS i/o (see:
# compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec), not more.
multithreaded_compaction: false

# Throttles compaction to the given total throughput across the entire
# system. The faster you insert data, the faster you need to compact in
# order to keep the sstable count down, but in general, setting this to
# 16 to 32 times the rate you are inserting data is more than sufficient.
# Setting this to 0 disables throttling. Note that this account for all types
# of compaction, including validation compaction.
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

# Track cached row keys during compaction, and re-cache their new
# positions in the compacted sstable.  Disable if you use really large
# key caches.
compaction_preheat_key_cache: true

# Throttles all outbound streaming file transfers on this node to the
# given total throughput in Mbps. This is necessary because Cassandra does
# mostly sequential IO when streaming data during bootstrap or repair, which
# can lead to saturating the network connection and degrading rpc performance.
# When unset, the default is 200 Mbps or 25 MB/s.
# stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 200

# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 20000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

# Enable operation timeout information exchange between nodes to accurately
# measure request timeouts.  If disabled, replicas will assume that requests
# were forwarded to them instantly by the coordinator, which means that
# under overload conditions we will waste that much extra time processing
# already-timed-out requests.
#
# Warning: before enabling this property make sure to ntp is installed
# and the times are synchronized between the nodes.
cross_node_timeout: false
# Enable socket timeout for streaming operation.
# When a timeout occurs during streaming, streaming is retried from the start
# of the current file. This _can_ involve re-streaming an important amount of
# data, so you should avoid setting the value too low.
# Default value is 0, which never timeout streams.
# streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms: 0

# phi value that must be reached for a host to be marked down.
# most users should never need to adjust this.
# phi_convict_threshold: 8

# endpoint_snitch -- Set this to a class that implements
# IEndpointSnitch.  The snitch has two functions:
# - it teaches Cassandra enough about your network topology to route
#   requests efficiently
# - it allows Cassandra to spread replicas around your cluster to avoid
#   correlated failures. It does this by grouping machines into
#   "datacenters" and "racks."  Cassandra will do its best not to have
#   more than one replica on the same "rack" (which may not actually
#   be a physical location)
#
# IF YOU CHANGE THE SNITCH AFTER DATA IS INSERTED INTO THE CLUSTER,
# YOU MUST RUN A FULL REPAIR, SINCE THE SNITCH AFFECTS WHERE REPLICAS
# ARE PLACED.
#
# Out of the box, Cassandra provides
#  - SimpleSnitch:
#    Treats Strategy order as proximity. This can improve cache
#    locality when disabling read repair.  Only appropriate for
#    single-datacenter deployments.
#  - GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
#    This should be your go-to snitch for production use.  The rack
#    and datacenter for the local node are defined in
#    cassandra-rackdc.properties and propagated to other nodes via
#    gossip.  If cassandra-topology.properties exists, it is used as a
#    fallback, allowing migration from the PropertyFileSnitch.
#  - PropertyFileSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    explicitly configured in cassandra-topology.properties.
#  - Ec2Snitch:
#    Appropriate for EC2 deployments in a single Region. Loads Region
#    and Availability Zone information from the EC2 API. The Region is
#    treated as the datacenter, and the Availability Zone as the rack.
#    Only private IPs are used, so this will not work across multiple
#    Regions.
#  - Ec2MultiRegionSnitch:
#    Uses public IPs as broadcast_address to allow cross-region
#    connectivity.  (Thus, you should set seed addresses to the public
#    IP as well.) You will need to open the storage_port or
#    ssl_storage_port on the public IP firewall.  (For intra-Region
#    traffic, Cassandra will switch to the private IP after
#    establishing a connection.)
#  - RackInferringSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    assumed to correspond to the 3rd and 2nd octet of each node's IP
#    address, respectively.  Unless this happens to match your
#    deployment conventions, this is best used as an example of
#    writing a custom Snitch class and is provided in that spirit.
#
# You can use a custom Snitch by setting this to the full class name
# of the snitch, which will be assumed to be on your classpath.
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

# controls how often to perform the more expensive part of host score
# calculation
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
# controls how often to reset all host scores, allowing a bad host to
# possibly recover
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
# if set greater than zero and read_repair_chance is < 1.0, this will allow
# 'pinning' of replicas to hosts in order to increase cache capacity.
# The badness threshold will control how much worse the pinned host has to be
# before the dynamic snitch will prefer other replicas over it.  This is
# expressed as a double which represents a percentage.  Thus, a value of
# 0.2 means Cassandra would continue to prefer the static snitch values
# until the pinned host was 20% worse than the fastest.
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

# request_scheduler -- Set this to a class that implements
# RequestScheduler, which will schedule incoming client requests
# according to the specific policy. This is useful for multi-tenancy
# with a single Cassandra cluster.
# NOTE: This is specifically for requests from the client and does
# not affect inter node communication.
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler - No scheduling takes place
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.RoundRobinScheduler - Round robin of
# client requests to a node with a separate queue for each
# request_scheduler_id. The scheduler is further customized by
# request_scheduler_options as described below.
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

# Scheduler Options vary based on the type of scheduler
# NoScheduler - Has no options
# RoundRobin
#  - throttle_limit -- The throttle_limit is the number of in-flight
#                      requests per client.  Requests beyond
#                      that limit are queued up until
#                      running requests can complete.
#                      The value of 80 here is twice the number of
#                      concurrent_reads + concurrent_writes.
#  - default_weight -- default_weight is optional and allows for
#                      overriding the default which is 1.
#  - weights -- Weights are optional and will default to 1 or the
#               overridden default_weight. The weight translates into how
#               many requests are handled during each turn of the
#               RoundRobin, based on the scheduler id.
#
# request_scheduler_options:
#    throttle_limit: 80
#    default_weight: 5
#    weights:
#      Keyspace1: 1
#      Keyspace2: 5
# request_scheduler_id -- An identifier based on which to perform
# the request scheduling. Currently the only valid option is keyspace.
# request_scheduler_id: keyspace

# Enable or disable inter-node encryption
# Default settings are TLS v1, RSA 1024-bit keys (it is imperative that
# users generate their own keys) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as the cipher
# suite for authentication, key exchange and encryption of the actual data transfers.
# Use the DHE/ECDHE ciphers if running in FIPS 140 compliant mode.
# NOTE: No custom encryption options are enabled at the moment
# The available internode options are : all, none, dc, rack
#
# If set to dc cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the DCs
# If set to rack cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the racks
#
# The passwords used in these options must match the passwords used when generating
# the keystore and truststore.  For instructions on generating these files, see:
# http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore
#
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    # require_client_auth: false

# enable or disable client/server encryption.
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    # require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    # truststore: conf/.truststore
    # truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]

# internode_compression controls whether traffic between nodes is
# compressed.
# can be:  all  - all traffic is compressed
#          dc   - traffic between different datacenters is compressed
#          none - nothing is compressed.
internode_compression: all

# Enable or disable tcp_nodelay for inter-dc communication.
# Disabling it will result in larger (but fewer) network packets being sent,
# reducing overhead from the TCP protocol itself, at the cost of increasing
# latency if you block for cross-datacenter responses.
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false

# Enable or disable kernel page cache preheating from contents of the key cache after compaction.
# When enabled it would preheat only first "page" (4KB) of each row to optimize
# for sequential access. Note: This could be harmful for fat rows, see CASSANDRA-4937
# for further details on that topic.
preheat_kernel_page_cache: false
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions you could try:

1. Adjust your Python code to catch the AllServersUnavailable exception and pause before retrying. You can see an example of this in the answer to this SO question: [How to handle AllServersUnavailable Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906550/how-to-handle-allserversunavailable-exception)
2. Switch from pycassa to the [DataStax Python driver](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver). The [pycassa](https://github.com/pycassa/pycassa) project is recommending that developers use to the new driver for new projects.